# recursive function to fill an array with childs

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm in a javascript project, and I have to draw a tree using canvas. Like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Types

Each node represents a window in my project, and each sub-node is a child of the previous node.

I'm sure that I have to use an array, like:

```
var node = {
    windowId,
    childs{}
}
```

That is, the node would be the root, with its id (windowId) and **childs{}** is another array that will have the same structure.

For example:

```
var node = {
        windowId,
        childs{
            windowId //windowId of the child
            childs{}
        }
    }
   .
   .
   .
```

I'm creating a recursive function, but I haven't almost nothing...could you help me,please?

Comment: You should first learn JavaScript syntax. Make the `childs` property of your node object an `Array` of other node-object. And please show us the code you have come up with, it's not that complicated (and you've got sample codes in the linked Wikipedia article)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a question here. We're not going to do the design for you, though we can help if you formulate a _specific_ question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each node can become top-level, then all you have to do is figure out a structure that always allows childs. Extending your example, it would be pretty easy to make each list of childs an array.

```
{ 
    id: 0,
    childs: [
      { 
       id: 0.1,
       childs: [ ... ]
      },
      {
      id: 0.2,
      childs: [ ... ]
      },
       ...
    ]
}
```

For the rest, store the current object in a variable, then go through each leaf and add the corresponding indent. If you do it right, you can have a single draw function and call it as many times as you need; you just need to keep track of the level.

Comment: Thanks very much Andrei. Maybe my question isn't very descriptive, but it's because I know that you can't make the work for me...I'm only looking for a track. Thanks.